# How to change reply_to email address in Vtiger 6.4 for all the outgoing mails via Mail Manager?

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

When any user sends any email via Mail Manager, the default `reply_to` email address is set as the `Help_desk_emailid` by Vtiger. I want to change that `reply_to` email address and want to use some custom dynamic email address for all the outgoing emails via **Mail manager only; not for any other outgoing emails such as events, reminders etc.**

It would be really helpful even if i need to do that directly in the code in core files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the emails through Mail Manager are sent via different module and not using `/modules/Emails/mail.php`

All the emails are sent from `/modules/Emails/models/Record.php` via `send()` function.

So to change the **reply_to** email address we need to modify below line in `send()` function:

`$replyTo = $currentUserModel->get('email1');`

Comment: Yes Sasha, You just have to change the User's Primary Email address from My Preference Settings to change Reply to Email address.

Answer (score 1):

You can change reply to email address in `/modules/Emails/mail.php`

```
    if(isUserInitiated()) {
        $replyToEmail = $from_email;
    } else {
        $replyToEmail = $from_email_field;
    }
```

Just change the logic of getting from email address or else you can add static email address.

Comment: I tried to edit the email address but it seems like it is not being used by the mail manager. It does not reflect into my outgoing email sent via mail manager. I cross checked that by editing mail content from code level also. 

Can you suggest any other fixes? I just want to know which mail function sends the email.